# OWASP ZAP Not receiving Alerts for subsequent active scan

Tags: javascript, security, zap

I have been using ZAP to find any final kinks for a website I'm working on. Everything is working great except for I've noticed that there are no alerts being logged in the ZAP gui when I run an active scan following a passive spider.

The initial passive scan for a new session logs alerts just fine but I'd really like to see the alerts from the active scan. Am I missing something? I tried restarting a new session and going straight to attacking but it's still not logging anything. Does it maybe need to finish before it starts logging the alerts? I have checked the generated html report and it doesn't indicate whether the alert was flagged by a passive or active scan so I really can't tell. I doubt there are so few vulrnabilities in my little web app.

If anyone has an idea as to what setting I'm missing or if I'm doing something wrong I'd appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I may have found what was going on. I checked the real time scan progress and ZAP skipped many attacks because of low rule limits I set to speed up the scan.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How are you exploring your app?
The number of requests are very low, that suggests to me that you are not exploring your app effectively.
You can either explore the app manually (which proxying your browser through ZAP) or using automation via:

- The standard spider (fast, but doesnt handle javascript so well)
- The ajax spider (slower, but launches browsers so handled JS well)
- Your own unit tests (good but only if you have some)

Have a look at you app in the Sites tree - if it doesnt appear to be showing as many pages as you expect then you need to focus on exploring your app more effectively.
The active scanner doesnt do any exploring, it only attacks the urls you've found by other means.